# Why does screensharing with WebRTC works on tablet but not on phone [android]?

Tags: android, webrtc

Phone: Nexus 5
Tablet: Nexus 7

On tablet the logs are clean with the dimensions being rendered etc. But on phone I see extra logs for MediaCodecVideoDecoder which says decoder format changed

```
    06-05 10:05:10.606 10880 11319 D MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Decoder format changed: {image-data=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=80,capacity=80], mime=video/raw, crop-top=0, crop-right=1127, slice-height=1200, color-format=19, height=1200, width=1128, what=1869968451, crop-bottom=1199, crop-left=0, stride=1136}
    06-05 10:05:10.606 10880 11319 D MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Color: 0x13
    06-05 10:05:10.606 10880 11319 D MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Frame stride and slice height: 1136 x 1200
    06-05 10:05:10.621 10880 11327 D FreeVideoRendererGui: ID: 1. YuvImageRenderer.setSize: 1128 x 1200 rotation 0
    06-05 10:05:10.622 10880 11327 D FreeVideoRendererGui:   YuvImageRenderer.setSize done.
    06-05 10:05:10.626 10880 11149 D FreeVideoRendererGui: ID: 1. AdjustTextureCoords. Display: 1080.0 x 1170.0. Video: 1128 x 1200. Rotation: 0. Mirror: false
    06-05 10:05:10.626 10880 11149 D FreeVideoRendererGui:   Texture vertices: (-1.0,-0.9864975) - (1.0,0.48649752)
    06-05 10:05:10.626 10880 11149 D FreeVideoRendererGui:   Texture UV: (0.0,0.0) - (1.0,1.0)
    06-05 10:05:10.626 10880 11149 D FreeVideoRendererGui:   AdjustTextureCoords done
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: I don't know why this is happening. But I'm trying to accomplish screensharing from WebRTC on Android. Can you share with me how you did it? Maybe if I run into similar issues it can help you as well. Thanks